# Javascript Infovis Tool: Add labels to Hypertree

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

I am new to JIT and finding it difficult to add labels to Hypertree example1.js. I tried following [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit/Q5RBlL_PCPI) discussion, but no success.

Any help would be really appreciated.